# German sentence translation

Tags: translation

Could you help me with the following sentence that needs to be translated into German?

"The payment for the invoice 167 might have entered your account on 30.12.2019."

Comment: Please notice that translation services are off topic here. However, we could help you, when you edit your post, as your own translation plus a  description what exactly you're uncertain about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Die Zahlung für die Rechnung 167 könnte am 30.12.2019 auf Ihrem Konto eingegangen sein.

Comment: oder '_Der Rechnungsbetrag der Rechnung Nr. 167 könnte Ihrem Konto am 30.12.2019 gutgeschrieben worden sein._'